# Can not select many items from list using LINQ or lambda query

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7, select, lambda

I have list of objects in static class. Something like that:

```c#
public static class ClassOfItems
{
     private static List<Item> ListOfItems = new List<Item>();
     public static List<Item> GetAll()
     {
        return ListOfItems;
     }
}
public class Item
{
     public int id{get; set;}
     public string name{get;set:}
}
```

I initialize items from XML file. Until that moment everything is OK. For example i have two items inside my static class:

```c#
item1:
   id=1
   name="item1"

item2:
   id=2
   name="item2"
```

Now I want to select items where id value is more then 0 (for example):

1 way:

```c#
var items=from i in ClassOfItems.GetAll()
          where i.id>0
          select i;
```

2 way:

```c#
var items=ClassOfItems.GetAll().Where(i => i.id>0);
```

Both of them not working :(

I just noticed that when I use methods with returns single objects it's working. For example:

```c#
var items=ClassOfItems.GetAll().First(i => i==1);//it's working
var items=ClassOfItems.GetAll().Where(i=> i==1);//not working ;(
```

---

haha solved
sorry guys :D
just needed to use ToList() method.

```cs
var items=(ClassOfItems.GetAll().Where(i => i.id>0)).ToList();
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working". Is an exception thrown? Are you only seeing one result when you are expecting two?

Comment: I expecting more then 1 result but im getting nulls: http://oi40.tinypic.com/2hp6t08.jpg I'm using Where method

Comment: @TomaszDev, your where method is working since from beginning.Just you don't try it with foreach and you thought it is not working.

Comment: yes. I lost more than an hour before I noticed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/bb548891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)you will see [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/bb548891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  and [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods returning `IEnumerable<TResult>`, even if your sequence has a one element,it doesn't matter.

Actually your Where method working as expected.If you loop through your list with `foreach` after Where you will  see I'm correct.Enumerable extension methods using yield return, and that's why you can't see a list in the debugger.Instead you see `WhereListIterator.`You can take a look at this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) for more details about yield keyword.

> You consume an iterator method by using a foreach statement or LINQ query. Each iteration of the foreach loop calls the iterator method. When a yield return statement is reached in the iterator method, expression is returned, and the current location in code is retained. Execution is restarted from that location the next time that the iterator function is called.

However,If you want to get a list just use `ToList` method after where like this:

```
var items=ClassOfItems.GetAll().Where(i=> i==1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Select()` transforms an object. So in your last Select statement, you are returning a `bool`

You would use `First(i=> i.id==1)` or `FirstOrDefault(i=> i.id==1)` if you are expecting one result, or `Where(i=> i.id==1)` if you're expecting multiple results.

Comment: var items=ClassOfItems.GetAll().Where(i=> i.id>0); //not working too ;(

Comment: Are you expecting one result? Then use `FirstOrDefault(i=>i.id==1)` which returns `null` or one result.

Comment: I expecting multiple results. I'm using Where but i'm getting this:  http://oi40.tinypic.com/2hp6t08.jpg

Comment: Have you verified that the `GetAll()` method contains all elements?

Comment: Can you post sample code of how the specific objects are being bound to and being inserted into the collection?